# ResponseEntity redirecting to a new page, while I want it to remain in the same page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, response

When I am pressing delete button I am redirected to the link attached to this button while I want be the same page while I use `ResponseEntity`.
Here is the button:

```html
<td><a type="button" class="btn btn-warning" href="/delete-todo?id=${todo.id}">DELETE</a></td>
```

Here is my controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/delete-todo")
public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteTodo(@RequestParam int id){
    todoService.delete(id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

[After pressing delete button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqg8P.png)

[The delete button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bpO0.png)

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong with `ResponseEntity`.

Comment: Are you using Thymeleaf? Or what is your view technology? The problem is that you are using a link to call the action.

Comment: yes, i m use jsp as view. What should i do?

Comment: Initially i was using this code,
`@RequestMapping(value="/delete-todo")
 public String deleteTodo(@RequestParam int id){
  todoService.delete(id);
  return "redirect:/todo-list";
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply return remove redirect should work:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/delete-todo")   
public String deleteTodo(@RequestParam int id){         
   todoService.delete(id);      
   return "/todo-list";     
}
```

Comment: How can i use ResponseEntity and a view together. Such the that I can use my view and also customized http response?

Comment: You can't. The one that returns String is to render the view. And on with Response Entity is a REST endpoint.

Comment: Ohh so u mean REST APIs can only be used to get the data or information, and some other application will use this data to display info on the web page. Am I right?

Comment: You want to use JSP for our view. So you don't need REST.

Comment: Yes that's what i mean, rest apis are only for supplying data, some other app will consume my rest service.

Comment: Ok so is your question answered?